# How do I edit those custom Terminal commands to solve my issue?

Tags: bash, terminal, alias

I was trying to compile in terminal my `fortran1.f95` file in `~/` folder, as such I ran `gfortran -x f95 -o fortran1 ~/fortran1.f95`. I made a couple of terminal `alias`, here there are:

```
alias e1f95c="gfortran -x f95 -o fortran1 ~/fortran1.f95"

alias e1f95cr="gfortran -x f95 -o fortran1 ~/fortran1.f95; open ~/fortran1"

alias e1f95e="open ~/fortran1.f95"

alias e1f95r="open ~/fortran1"
```

I wrote `e1` to represent 'exercise1', `f95` to represent the compiling language specification and `c, r, cr, e` to represent 'compile, run, compile and run, edit'.

Here's my issue: I don't know how to make a flexible alias for when I will add more files, for instance when I make a new file called `fortran2` I'd like to run `e2f95cr` and get the same result.

What I tried: found there is a file called `.bashrc` that can sorta can be coded into doing what I'd like, but I can't find it and don't know how to proceed once I open it.

Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: Use functions rather than aliases, they can take arguments.

Comment: Could you please elaborate just a bit more on that one?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.bashrc` file is located in your home directory. Try `ls -la ~` -- if you don't see it there, it's because it doesn't exist, so it's OK to create one.

In some circumstances bash will not process that file, so you can put this line in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` (whichever one exists)

```
[[ -r ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

Now, about your alias question: I might do something like this

```
# a function
do_f95() {
    local action=$1 exercise=$2
    if [[ -z $exercise ]]; then
        echo "error: specify the exercise number" >&2
        echo "usage: $FUNCNAME action exerciseNum" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    local filebase="$HOME/fortran${exercise}"
    local compile=false run=false
    case "$action" in 
        e) open "$filebase.f95"; return ;;
        c) compile=true ;;
        r) run=true ;;
        cr) compile=true; run=true ;;
        *) echo "error: unknown action" >&2; return 1 ;;
    esac
    $compile && gfortran -x f95 -o "$filebase" "$filebase.f95"
    $run && open "$filebase"
}

# some aliases
alias fc='do_f95 c'
alias fcr='do_f95 cr'
alias fr='do_f95 r'
alias fe='do_f95 e'
```

And then you'd use it like:

```
fe 1         # to edit ~/fortran1.f95
fc 1         # to compile it
fr 1         # to run it
```

You can specify any exercise number and it will use the appropriate `~/fortranN.f95` file

Comment: Thank you, very kind of you. Looking forward to being as smart as you one day!